# Pick out the correct choices for a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

let $f(x)=\dfrac{e^{\large \frac{-1}{x}}}{x}$ where $x\in (0,1)$ .then on $(0,1)$

1.$f$ is uniformly continuous

2.$f$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous

3.$f$ is bounded

4.$f$ is not continuous

I found it to be continuous but not uniformly as $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)$ does not exist.It is bounded below by 0 and above by 1.Am i right? 
Would be grateful if someone could suggest me required edits.

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^{-1/x}}x\stackrel{y=\frac1x}=\lim_{y\to\infty } \frac y{e^{y}}\stackrel {l'H}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac1{e^y}=0$$ so the limit exists (finitely) when $\;x\to 0^+\;$

Comment: thanks @Timbuc for your answer

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x}=0$$
therefore the function is uniformly continuous because you can prolonge $x\mapsto \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x}$ to $0$ and the prolongement is continuous on $[0,1]$. But you know that a continuous function on a compact is uniformly continuous, therefore it's uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ and thus on $]0,1[$.

We can then conclude that 1. and 3. are true and 2. and 4. wrong.

Answer (score 0):

f is bounded beaouse limit to 0+ exists, and on (0,1] is continious is we define f(0)=0 than f is continious in [0,1]=> f have max on [0,1], f on compact that is contunious is uniform continious.

Comment: This answer, in spite of its being written unclearly and having some tiny gaps (which the OP can complete) in its argumentation, is correct. Why the downvote? +1